# Appropriate data structure for a long string made of key - value pairs

Tags: java, string, data-structures, fixed

I have a requirement to send a message to another system.
The message is in the form of a string made of multiple key-value pairs. It's what's called a fixed message.They key is predefined int and the value a string,int,float etc

Eq:

```
   beginKey=XA#|key1=value1|key2=value2 ...
```

Some of these fields have default, some are static, some get modified or computed when the object is build.

I thought of using a simple pojo with each field being a Pair<Integer,String> trying to have in this way all the information : the key, value and the name of the field.
I also thought providing a builder that can set some defaults as well.

How would you model an object to keep this data and interact with it in a clean way.

Any idea to make this better is appreciated ?
Thanks

```
@Builder
public class Message {

@Builder.Default
private Pair<Integer, String> beginKey = Pair.of(123,"XA#");
private Pair<Integer, String> key1;
private Pair<Integer, String> key2;
...

public String toString() {

  StringJoiner formattedString = new StringJoiner("|");
  formattedString.add(beginKey);
  formattedString.add(key1);
  formattedString.add(key2);
  
  return formattedString.toString();
}
```

Comment: It depends on how you will use `Message`. I'm of the opinion that any input should be parsed immediately to an internally useful form, and formatting occur only upon output. So if message fields mean something, define fields with proper names and types (`int`, `String`, `SomeEnum`, etc.). Otherwise if you just need to move the contents around blindly, a `Map` of `Pair`s would be fine.

Comment: Problem with proper names and types is that the information carried by a field needs to contain : it's name, an id and a value.
Besides using Pair, I would declare my own type that has an id and a value, but that will be very similar to a Pair.

Comment: My other suggestion was a `Map` to map the names to pairs, but again, that depends on how you use them in the end. Without knowing that, that's the best I can suggest.